# Routing with Angular2 (404 page missing)

Tags: angular

I have an app in Angular2 where I need to pass two parameters from one component to the other through routing. These are the main app routes:

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '',      component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'correlation', loadChildren: './+mep-correlation#MepCorrelationModule'},
  { path: '**',    component: NoContentComponent },
];
```

Inside the module another component is used called ShowcaseComponent where the user makes a few selections and then presses a confirm button. This button opens up a Dialog component with a summary of the user's selections where they must confirm again if they are sure of their choices.

The confirm button on this dialog is supposed to route to the same url but with 2 parameters:

```
public confirmShowcase() {
  this.dialogRef.close();
  this.router.navigate(
    ['configuration', {
      concept : this.selectedConcept.id ,
      level : this.selectedLevel
     }
    ]
  );
}
```

And here are the routes for the Correlation Module:

```
export const routes = [
  { path: '', component: MepCorrelationComponent , children: [
    { path: 'configuration', children: [
      { path: 'concept:id', children: [
        { path: 'level:id' , component: MepCorrelationConfigurationComponent }
      ]}
    ]}
  ]}
];
```

`MepCorrelationConfigurationComponent` is a component of the module.

Then in this component I want to read the route parameters so I can use them when calling a service:

```
public ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params
    .switchMap((params: Params) => {
      return this.correlationService
        .loadCorrelationData(params['concept'], params['level']);
    }).subscribe(
      (correlationData) => {
        this._store.dispatch(
          new LoadCorrelationDataAction(correlationData)
        );
      }
    );
}
```

The problem I'm currently experiencing is that whenever I click the confirm button on my dialog component and the page tries to redirect to `http://localhost:3000/#/configuration;concept=14;level=3` for example, I get a 404 page missing error. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Changed the Module routes to:

```
export const routes = [
  { path: '', children: [
    { path: '', component: MepCorrelationComponent },
      { path: 'configuracion', children: [
        { path: '/:concepto/:nivel', component: MepCorrelationConfigurationComponent }
      ]}
    ]}
 ];
```

And tried the navigate method in various ways to no avail:

**Routes to 404:**

```
this.router.navigate([
  'correlation/configuration',
  {
    concept: this.selectedConcept.id,
    level: this.selectedLevel
  }
]);
```

**Routes to empty page:**

```
this.router.navigate([
  'correlation/configuration',
  this.selectedConcept.id,
  this.selectedLevel
]);
```

Comment: configuration instead of configuracion in the routes for the Correlation Module

Comment: Sorry missed that when translating my code from Spanish to English, its fine on my side.

Comment: use `/` instead of `;` http://localhost:3000/#/configuration/concept=14/level=3

Comment: Angular2 automatically puts those `;` on the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to resolve this, I think the problem was that I was mixing up optional and required router parameters.

The module routes ended up like this:

```
export const routes = [
  { path: '', children: [
    { path: '', component: MepCorrelationComponent },
    { path: 'configuracion/:conceptId/:levelId', component: MepCorrelationConfigurationComponent }
  ]},
];
```

And called the navigate method like this:

```
this.router.navigate([
 `correlacion/configuracion/${this.selectedConcept.id}/${this.selectedLevel}`
]);
```

This now loads my configuration component.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

http://localhost:3000/#/configuration/concept/14/level/3

```
 export const routes = [
      { path: '', component: MepCorrelationComponent , children: [
        { path: 'configuration', children: [
          { path: 'concept/:c_id', children: [
            { path: 'level/:id' , component: MepCorrelationConfigurationComponent }
          ]}
        ]}
      ]}
    ];
```

use different name of id so you can easily access them in the `ActivatedRoute` service.

note : the right way to make deep link is like this :
https://web.facebook.com/groups/groupID/permalink/postID/